# Chrome-like extensions in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, add-on

I have an idea for an extension that I would like to try to implement across all of the major browsers. Currently Chrome, Opera, and Safari all implement extensions more or less the same way (HTML and Javascript... basically a pseudo web page), and Firefox is capable of emulating this.

That leaves the "old reliable" Internet Explorer to deal with. Is it possible to implement an extension in it that can act akin to how extensions act in Chrome, Opera, and Safari? I would want as identical an experience as possible across all the browsers.

Comment: GreaseMonkey can work across the browsers even in IE; if that's what your are looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome Frame, it will cover Google Chrome and Internet explorer.

http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I'm specifically talking about extensions, and whether or not they can be built for Internet Explorer like they are for Chrome (button on the address bar, pressing it reveals a pseudo-web page).